# Make ColorTween forward to end immediately and reverse normally without changing the controller in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have the following code:

```dart
Animation _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: Colors.black, end: Colors.white).animate(animation);

AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: _colorTween,
  builder: (_, _) => customBuilder(_colorTween.value),
),
```

The variable `animation` is from another widget, which I can not change it at all. I even can not control the animation's forward and reverse because that is controlled by another built-in widget.

So I am wondering if I can make the color becomes Colors.white immediately when the forward is called. For the reverse, I am OK with the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I wouldn't name your input Animation `'_colorTween'`. That's just confusing since it's an animation!

But since you're already using a custom builder, you could likely do something like this in the custom build function:

```dart
switch(_colorTween.status) {
case AnimationStatus.forward:
  return <Colors.white or something like it>
default:
  return <normal calculation>
}
```

Although this could result in something slightly weird if the animation runs half way, then changes direction. You could put more logic in there to handle that though if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this excellent solution. It works very well. I also change my variable name from `'_colorTween'` to ``_colorAnimation``. Thanks for this correction too. 